# Rename the fields base on the first record content of each one

Tags: mysql, csv

Ihave the scheme below,

[phpMyAdmin - Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PX3RZ.png)

is made by an import from the csv file, 
how can I rename the fields base on the first record content of each one?

**like:**

1. rename: COL 1 to: User ID
2. rename: COL 2 to: Main - Full Name
3. rename: COL 3 to: Main - First name
   and so on ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before importing CSV data remove the first line with columns names from the file. Then, in the phpmyadmin while importing CSV file in advanced options, it is possible to put comma separated list of *column names* (that's the name of the input field) which match the CSV columns.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I was looking for a SQL solution because in that way I can filter / sanitize the fields name that contains freaks characters, that make fail the PhpMyAdmin import.

Comment: You can still "clean" the column names during the import of the CSV. Just put a "clean" comma separated list of columns names. Seems to be easier than writing a SQL query.

Comment: Anyway, as far as I know there is no direct way to combine ALTER + SELECT. You can still create the procedure that will SELECT column names, store it in a variable and run the ALTER query using the variable. In the end you can remove the row with names from the table.

Answer (score 0):

php approach: [renameField.php](https://gist.github.com/Fabio-Ottaviani-Dev/d602e4abd5b9c22a7e24b053ed1b290d)

maybe it's not the most elegant solution, but it does it's job.